# How do I link to a heading and cause a click event to fire when the link is clicked in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bunch of links in my footer and I want to link to different headings on a page and create a click event so a associated paragraph changes from `display: none` to `display: block`.

Put another way: You see headings and a footer with links (like the demo). You click the footer links and the screen should jump to (link to) an associated h2 and display a previously hidden and associated p.

Here is what I have:   I can display the paragraphs when I click on the headings directly (adapted from a stackoverflow post). I can link to the headings when I click on the links in the footer. But I need to display the associated paragraph and link to a heading (both) when I click the footer links.

Here is my markup so far:

```
<div class="service">
     <h2 class="page services"><img class="img-bullet-services" src="websiteDot.png" alt="alt">service1</h2>

    <p class="p-on-white service-desc p-hide" id="service1">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
</div>
</br>
<div class="service">
     <h2 class="page services"><img class="img-bullet-services" src="websiteDot.png" alt="alt">service2</h2>

    <p class="p-on-white service-desc p-hide" id="service2">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
</div>
<div id="col4-footer" class="four-cols-footer four-cols">
    <ul>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
             <h3><a class="a-bold" href="Services.php">Services</a></h3>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Services.php#services1">service1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="Services.php#service2">seervice2</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.p-hide {
    display: none;
}
```

js:

```
var services = document.getElementsByClassName('service'),
    servicedesc;
for (var i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
    services[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        servicedesc = this.getElementsByClassName('service-desc');
        for (var j = 0; j < servicedesc.length; j++) {
            servicedesc[j].classList.toggle('p-hide');
        }
    });
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/4GgRY/

I need the solution in vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: how could it be possible to handle events without js??

Comment: js is okay. I just don't want to use jquery. I know jquery is js, but I want use js directly. I'll edit my question.

Comment: if you are using javascript then why not to use jquery? It will make your task easier..

Comment: I was told it is better to learn js before using jquery. And I was told using jquery needlessly causes code bloat. I'm new to this...

Comment: I can't help but wonder why people feel the need to urge others towards a (largely unnecessary) library for the sake of 'simplicity,' rather than respecting someone's constraints, limitations and preferences...as regards the question itself, though: are the headings linked-to,  the footer, on the same page or different page(s)?

Comment: The footer is the same across all pages. In reality (not in my example) the footer links go to different pages, but the behavior I am looking for only applies to the Services.php page. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @DavidThomas Could you please elaborate on the "largely unnecessary" part? While I in general agree that jQuery is used more often than not as an answer to a non-problem that can be solved without, this isn't really the case here (events done right without jQuery across major browsers - I don't think you want to reengineer that - except one wants to learn some stuff the vey hard way which is obiously not the case here). So, I can't help but wonder why people feel the need to urge others not to use an awesome library that levels browsers inconsistencies for the sake of "i-don't-know-what"…

Comment: I don't feel any need to urge people either way (to use or otherwise), I'm happy for the most part simply to accept that people will, and *can*, use, or not-use, whatever tool they wish. Personally, I *like* jQuery (I think that was my first gold badge, too) but I get a little wearied seeing nearly every answer to a JS problem (regardless of tagging) resulting in a jQuery answer. Yes, it's great, but it's not always needed. Explaining why it's largely unnecessary? Let me refer you to: [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this works

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>internav</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .hideclass{
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="service" id="div1">
     <h2 class="page services"><img class="img-bullet-services" src="websiteDot.png" alt="alt">service1</h2>

    <p class="service-desc" id="service1">
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br>
    </p>
</div>
</br>
<div class="service" id="div2">
     <h2 class="page services"><img class="img-bullet-services" src="websiteDot.png" alt="alt">service2</h2>

    <p class="service-desc" id="service2">
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br>
    </p>
</div>


<div id="col4-footer" class="four-cols-footer four-cols">
    <ul>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
             <h3><a class="a-bold" href="Services.php">Services</a></h3>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#div1" data-toggle="service1" onclick="toggle(this)">service1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#div2" data-toggle="service2" onclick="toggle(this)">seervice2</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle (link) {
        target = link.getAttribute("data-toggle");
        servides = document.getElementsByClassName('service-desc');//.className += " hideclass";
        for (var i = servides.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            //servides[i].className -= " hideclass";
            servides[i].className = "service-desc hideclass";
        };
        document.getElementById(target).className = "service-desc";
    }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was looking to show just the paragraph, not the entire div. So the headers are visible from the start, but not the paragraphs. but I think I can work with this. Thx!

Comment: my pleasure, please help me by ticking my answer... :)

Comment: If you can modify your answer so it does what was in the question I'll check it as the answer. I don't want to mislead newbies like me. This is how I get it done (you will have to move some markup around I think as well): var target, sericeDiv, pToDisplay
function toggle(link) {
    target = link.getAttribute("data-toggle");
    sericeDiv = document.getElementById(target)
    pToDisplay = sericeDiv.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
    pToDisplay.className = "p-on-white service-desc"
}

Answer (score 0):

Hello mountainclimber,

I hope this helps you out.

If I understand your question correctly, you wish to be able to navigate to the anchors within the page and at the same time un-hide a previously hidden

(or other) tag.

To that end I took your original example and developed a new version.  It may not be the very best version in the world, but I think it accomplishes what you asked.

The pertinent changes are as follows.

JS:

```
var useQuerySelector = false;
//Shim from jscheuer1 -- http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?68847-Why-getelementsbyclassname-not-working-IE
if (!document.getElementsByClassName) 
{
    document.getElementsByClassName =   function (cn) 
                                        { 
                                            var rx = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + cn+ "(?:$|\\s)");
                                            var allT = document.getElementsByTagName("*"), allCN = [],ac="", i = 0, a;
                                                while (a = allT[i=i+1]) 
                                                {
                                                  ac=a.className;
                                                  if ( ac && ac.indexOf(cn) !==-1) 
                                                  {
                                                    if(ac===cn)
                                                    { 
                                                        allCN[allCN.length] = a; continue;   
                                                    }

                                                    rx.test(ac) ? (allCN[allCN.length] = a) : 0;
                                                  }
                                                }
                                            return allCN;
                                        }
}    

//My own feature "sniffing"
try
{
    document.getElementByClassName('');
}
catch(ex)
{
    useQuerySelector = true;
}

function navigateToAnchor(anchorObject)
{
    var anchorName      = anchorObject.href.substring(anchorObject.href.lastIndexOf("#")+1, anchorObject.href.length)
    var tagObj          = document.getElementById(anchorName);
    var hiddenElements  = (!useQuerySelector?tagObj.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("p-hide"):tagObj.parentElement.querySelectorAll(".p-hide"));

    toggleElements(hiddenElements, false);
}    

function toggleElements(hiddenElements, bHide)
{
    var objCurrElement = null;

    for (i = 0; i < hiddenElements.length; i++)
    {
        objCurrElement = hiddenElements[i];

        if (objCurrElement != null && objCurrElement != 'undefined')
        {
            if (bHide)
            {
                //Add the p-hide class.
                objCurrElement.className += "p-hide";
            }
            else
            {
                //Remove the p-hide class.
                objCurrElement.className = objCurrElement.className.replace(/p\-hide/,'');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Alternatively, using a syntax I have never used before you could do it this way***

JS:

```
function toggleElements(hiddenElements, bHide)
{
    var objCurrElement = null;

    for (i = 0; i < hiddenElements.length; i++)
    {
        objCurrElement = hiddenElements[i];

        tmpObj = objCurrElement;
        if (objCurrElement != null && objCurrElement != 'undefined')
        {

            if (bHide)
            {
                //Add the p-hide class.
                objCurrElement.classList.add("p-hide");
            }
            else
            {
                //Remove the p-hide class.
                objCurrElement.classList.remove("p-hide");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
    <li><a href="#service1" onclick="return navigateToAnchor(this);">Service 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#service2" onclick="return navigateToAnchor(this);">Service 2</a></li>
```

That's what I have :)  I have tested it clean in the latest version of FireFox and Chrome as well as IE 8 and 9.

Please let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I asked the initial question and I got a good answer from g-newa, but here is an alternative (really a modification of what g-newa posted). To make it work you have to move the service1 and service2 ids up into the div:

js:

```
var target, sericeDiv, pToDisplay
function toggle(link) {
    target = link.getAttribute("data-toggle");
    sericeDiv = document.getElementById(target)
    pToDisplay = sericeDiv.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
    pToDisplay.className = "p-on-white service-desc"
    document.getElementById(target).className = "service-desc";
}
```

...seems to work. Just an alternative. Hope it helps. In words this is what it is doing: get data-toggle attribute value, use the data-toggle as an id to get the correct div, get the child p (paragraph) within the div, change the class so it is no longer includes p-hide class, move screen to the appropriate div.

If this not good in some way can you please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The complete solution INCLUDING links that work from the footer even when you AREN'T on the services page go here:
[link to heading on different page and make paragraph visible from footer link while not on linked-to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041956/link-to-heading-on-different-page-and-make-paragraph-visible-from-footer-link-wh)