# link to heading on different page and make paragraph visible from footer link while not on linked-to page

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question is a follow-up to this question:
[How do I link to a heading and cause a click event to fire when the link is clicked in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025470/how-do-i-link-to-a-heading-and-cause-a-click-event-to-fire-when-the-link-is-clic)

Basically I am trying to link from the footer on any page (the footer is the same across all pages) and do two things: move to the appropriate location on the page and display a previously hidden (display: none;) paragraph (p).

Here is the issue:
In the link above there aren't any solutions provided that allow for the situation where you are NOT on the services page (the page where the discussed links go). In other words, if you are not on the Services page and you click on a link to the services page the js is called and every happens the way it is suppose to except the paragraph isn't expanded. If I click on one of the service footer links while on the services page everything works fine.

How do I get the p to be display: block; when I am not on the services page (the page where I am linking too)?

I tried window.location, but that didn't seem to work. I also tried some solutions I found online for delaying the js until the page loads, but those didn't work either.

Thanks in advance.

ps - I'd like to see if there is a javascript solution, so no jquery please.

markup:

```
<div id="service1" class="service">
        <h2  class="page services" ><img class="img-bullet-services" src="websiteDot.png" alt="alt">service1</h2>
        <p class="p-on-white service-desc p-hide" >
           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        </p>
    </div>
    </br>
    <div id="service2" class="service">
        <h2 class="page services"><img class="img-bullet-services" src="websiteDot.png" alt="alt">service2</h2>
        <p class="p-on-white service-desc p-hide" > 
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        </p>
    </div>
<div id="col4-footer" class="four-cols-footer four-cols">
    <ul>
       <li style="list-style: none;"><h3><a class="a-bold" href="Services.php">Services</a></h3></li>

       <li><a href="Services.php#service1" data-toggle="service1" onclick="toggle(this)">service1</a></li>
       <li><a href="Services.php#service2" data-toggle="service2" onclick="toggle(this)">service2</a></li>

     </ul>
 </div>
```

js:

```
var target, sericeDiv, pToDisplay
function toggle(link) {

    target = link.getAttribute("data-toggle");

    sericeDiv = document.getElementById(target)
    pToDisplay = sericeDiv.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
    document.getElementById(target).className = "service-desc";
    pToDisplay.className = "p-on-white service-desc"

}
```

css:

```
.p-hide{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Wait for the window to load, check what paragraph you want to display (in your URL) and display it. Don't know what the problem is if you don't provide any code.

Comment: The code is in the link. I thought it better not to duplicate code, but I'll add it.

Comment: Code added as requested...

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understood completly the question but you could set the `href` as`#` set a data-attribute, something like a `data-href="your/location.html"` and create a method and set it  `onclick=yourProcess()` and when you need to redirect get the data-atribute if you want to delay something you could use `setTimeout()`

You should take a look for [data-attrib](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) ,[timing events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

I hope this helps...

Comment: I added code. Does that help? I don't really follow your solution, which is my fault for not including code.

Comment: If I understood, you need two things:
1 Show a hidden p
2 Redirect
is this true?

Comment: Yes, correct. But the issue is when you click on the footer link from a page other than Services, which doesn't seem to expand the p.

Comment: You could add some strings to the url set a method on ready and get the url (with document.URL) and split the strings by # searching by something and show or hide bassed on that

Comment: sorry, I am new to this. Not really sure how to pull that off.

Comment: You should modify the href property to set something that you should detect for the process http://jsfiddle.net/pXHhG/

Comment: I posted my final solution as an answer. Couldn't have done it without your jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0):

See my comments below, but this solved it for me. I can click on the footer links that go to the services page whether I am on the services page or not.

Major credit goes to MikeVelazco. Without his comments I couldn't have gotten this far.

markup:

```
<div id="service1" class="service">
        <h2  class="page services" ><img class="img-bullet-services" src="websiteDot.png" alt="alt">Financial Analysis, Enterprise Performance, & 
            Reporting</h2>
        <p class="p-on-white service-desc p-hide" id="p-service1" >
           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        </p>
    </div>
    </br>
    <div id="service2" class="service">
        <h2 class="page services"><img class="img-bullet-services" src="websiteDot.png" alt="alt">Software, Systems, & Office Automation 
            Solutions</h2>
        <p class="p-on-white service-desc p-hide" id="p-service2"  > 
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        </p>
    </div>
<div id="col4-footer" class="four-cols-footer four-cols">
    <ul>
       <li style="list-style: none;"><h3><a class="a-bold" href="Services.php">Services</a></h3></li>

       <li><a href="Services.php#service1" data-toggle="service1" onclick="toggle(this)">Financial Analysis & Reporting</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
// link from footer link to p in services that needs to be displayed when you are on the services page already
function toggle(link) {
    var target, sericeDiv, pToDisplay;
    target = link.getAttribute("data-toggle");
    sericeDiv = document.getElementById(target)
    pToDisplay = sericeDiv.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
    document.getElementById(target).className = "service-desc";
    pToDisplay.className = "p-on-white service-desc"

}

//when a footer link is clicked that goes to a service on the service page
//this makes the p below the heading display
function openP(){
    var theURL = document.URL;
    var gotArray = theURL.split("#");
    var pToDisplay = document.getElementById("p-" + gotArray[1]);
    pToDisplay.className = "p-on-white service-desc";
}
window.onload = openP();
```

css:

```
.p-hide{
    display: none;
}
```